# Tumbleweed Badge- how low exactly is "low views"?

Tags: support, badges

While reading the StackOverflow badges page, I came across the Tumbleweed badge: "Asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week".

My question is, what is the definition of "low views"?

Comment: Also see: [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397)

Comment: Looking at the recent list of awards on Stack Overflow, the highest value is 46. Suggesting a limit of 50. Not in front of the codebase, so can't check.

Comment: @Oded: then that's been tweaked for Stack Overflow..

Comment: @MartijnPieters - could be, though if so, that may be hardcoded. Again, not in front of the code, so can't check for certain

Comment: Low views is 60 and under. There is no special provision for Stack Overflow. @MartijnPieters (confirmed in code) - note that the posts you have linked to are speculations from other community members, based on values seen.

Comment: @Oded: yup, and Jeff being silent on the number. :-)

Comment: @Oded: updated the Meta.SE FAQ with that number now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you stole 30 reps from Oded!

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Correction: I stole *potential badges* from Oded. No rep on child Metas! :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh, was sure it's MSE as you linked from MSE faq here! :D

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Low views is at most 60 views in its first week of existence; [Oded checked the code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252304/tumbleweed-badge-how-low-exactly-is-low-views#comment7357_252304).

Comment: What's a "view"? Does GoogleBot views count?

Comment: @Pacerier: exactly what counts as a view is not public. I doubt GoogleBot counts here though.