# More information on badges

Tags: support, feature-request, badges

I was wondering whether it could be possible to provide more information on the achievement of some badges in particular. For example the following:

1. **Tumbleweed** - Asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week (what constitutes low views?)
2. **Precognitive** - Actively participated in the private beta (What exactly is a private beta? What constitutes active participation in it?)
3. **Rollback** - First rollback (What is a rollback and how is it done? Does it mean reverting a post to its previous edit?)

The description of these badges lack a sufficient explanation on how they can be achieved.

Comment: They're meant for you to go and discover on your own.

Comment: I guess that's part of the experience at StackOverflow then :) Thanks @BoltClock

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Low views = [60 or below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252304/tumbleweed-badge-how-low-exactly-is-low-views?noredirect=1#comment7357_252304). No votes = no up/downvotes, which *is not* necessarily a score of zero: if one person upvotes and one downvotes, your question says "0," but there have been **two** votes, so your question doesn't qualify. No answers and no comments are both self-explanatory.
2. You mention the [Precognitive Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/892/precognitive), but you give the description for the [Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/30/beta) badge, so I'll give you the details for each. Neither are awarded for Stack Overflow, however: both are only for [Stack Exchange 2.0 sites](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/) proposed on [Area 51](//area51.stackexchange.com).

- Precognitive: You [followed the proposal for the site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) before it entered the commitment phase.
- Beta: You participated in the private beta for the site (the period in which *only* people who committed to the proposal can access the site).

3. A rollback can be performed on any post by users with [full edit privileges](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), a privilege that is awarded at 2000 reputation. However, it can be performed by all users on any of their own posts. The button is located in the revision history (`https://stackoverflow.com/posts/postID/revisions`):

[image: Rollback in the revision history]